Moving 1 SD along one variable in multiple linear regression vs simple linear regression
In simple linear regression done via the usual least squares method, it can be easily shown that the estimated line passes through the point of means, $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ and moving one sample standard deviation (SD), $s_x$, along $x$ causes a change of $r s_y$ in the $y$ direction, where $r$ is the correlation between $x$ and $y$ and $s_y$ is the sample SD of the $y$ values of the input data set.
Do similar results hold for multiple linear regression also done via least squares? That is, is it true that the estimated plane passes through $(\bar{x}_1,\ldots,\bar{x}_p,\bar{y})$ and that holding all other explanatory variables constant, if we move one SD, $s_{x_1}$, along $x_1$, there will be a change of $r_{x_1y} s_y$ in the y direction?

Edited to add: Figured it out by actually doing a MLR using two explanatory variables and one response variable. While the regression plane (least squares) does pass through the point of the means, the other expected result that 1 SD movement in $x_1$ causes $r_{x_1y} s_y$ movement in $y$ is NOT true. In my example, there is nonzero covariance between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and perhaps that is the reason why it does not work in higher dimensions unless possibly there is 0 covariance between all the explanatory variables.
